# VS Code Error ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:12345

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-data-lake

I am using ADLS extension in VS Code to get access to the data stored in ADLS. After installing the extension and successfull login , I tried
 `ADL Preview File: Local run account , ADLS file Path.`

The file gets downloaded locally but when I try to preview it in VS Code. it shows this: 
`ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:12345.`

As output it shows:
`[Info] /Clusterdata/breslow.csv` is downloaded to `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\breslow.csv` and opened for preview.

Even when I tried opening the same file localy there is no data inside, there it also shows the `ECONNREFUSED` error.

When I preview the data in Azure portal , everything is fine. If i try previewing a local CSV file in VS Code there is no problem.

I would appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a Chrome issue with vs code.You must launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled in order for the extension to attach to it.

Also i would suggest you to use `ADLS:Download` file for better usability.

I found the solution, since I was facing the same issue myself.

You must launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled in order for the extension to attach to it.

**Windows**

Right click the Chrome shortcut, and select properties In the "target" field, append --remote-debugging-port=9222 Or in a command prompt, execute /chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=12345

**OS X**

In a terminal, execute /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222

**Linux**

In a terminal, launch google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug

Hope it helps.